# C# forms exe detected as virus

Tags: c#, mouseevent, keyboard-events, user32, virus

I have an exe that disables kb and mouse (using user32.dll hooks,  Cursor.Clip = BoundRect;
Cursor.Hide();) and asks user to verify identity with fingerprint whenever a specific network resource is accessed. keyboard and mouse are enabled when correct fingerprint is provided.

up un-till last week it was working fine. but now after some windows update, windows defender is detecting the exe as a trojan (win32/wacatac.B!ml)

on windows 10 machines (with latest windows updates) this is not happening. it is only happening on windows server 2016 machines.

any idea on how to avoid being detected as a virus (cannot add the exe in exceptions list due to company policy unless there is absolutely no other way around it)

Answer (score 2):

Please check in AssemblyInfo.cs with at least the "name, author, and description" field.
I had a similar issue and this solved the problem for me.